# What exactly does "(X row(s) affected)" mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I ran a simple query:

```
UPDATE table

SET user_id = '123456'

WHERE user_id = '234567'
```

Then I got the error message:

```
(2942 row(s) affected)
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__users__6B24EA82'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users'. The duplicate key value is (123456).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Does this mean that i have actually made changes to 2942 rows?  It doesn't appear that way.  I haven't had much luck in my searches.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This error doesn't make sense.  If there is a primary key constraint on `user_id`, then only one row would be affected by `where user_id = '234567'`.

Comment: No, it means that 2942 rows match the condition.

Comment: @DavideR. . . . According to the error, the column with the primary key *is* `user_id` -- the same column is being used for both the assignment and the `where`.  The rows returned does not make sense.  An equality comparison on a primary key should never return more than one row.  If this were a composite key, then the error message should include all the columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you are right. I was answering based on my knowledge of what the "rows affected" message means. Your answer about a trigger makes more sense.

Comment: That's why I was confused at first too.  There should be only one row that matches the unique key (user_id).  I was afraid that I may have changed all of those rows.  but when I looked..nothing had changed.  So is it reasonable to say that just because you see "x rows affected" it does not necessarily mean that x rows have changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this means you would have made changes to 2942 rows, except one or more of them violates the PRIMARY KEY constraint so they were rolled back.

Comment: @Sung . . . It is odd that you accepted this answer, because it doesn't seem possible based on the information in the question.  The primary key constraint seems to be on `user_id` (although there is a small possibility it is on some other column), so the `update` can affect at most one row.

Comment: @Holmes  I don't understand precisely what "doesn't seem possible."  I accepted your answer because your explanation seemed to answer my question.  I wanted to know if "x rows affected" meant x rows changed.  And from your answer, it sounded like "no."  Is it not the case?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `user_id` is a primary key (which the error message suggests based on the value in the error message), then the query:

```
UPDATE table
    SET user_id = '123456'
    WHERE user_id = '234567';
```

could never affect more than one row in `table`.  `user_id` is a primary key, so it is unique.  The `where` clause would choose at most one row.

This suggests that there is a trigger on the table.  I think the 2,942 is coming from a *trigger* not from this statement directly.  If I had to guess, it is an instead-of update trigger, probably affecting another table.

The error implies that you already have a row in the table where `user_id = '123456'`, so no updates should be made to that table.

(Note:  Variations on this idea are possible.  The trigger could be updating *another* table and the primary key violation could be there.  The above scenario seems the more likely scenario.)

Comment: That is a relief.  I just wanted to be sure.  Thanks for your input, Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

when updating the rows in your table with user_id = '234567' there has been some PK violation occurred during the update of probably 2943 row and all the previous updates gets rolled back. so your search is failing

if you think there are no duplicates in your table

please,refer [No duplicates exist but get Msg 2627](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b043913c-5fce-4a12-b934-cf69b2ad5b8f/no-duplicates-exist-but-get-msg-2627-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-in-object?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 2):

roll back happens because of pk violation and u don't see the updates of previous rows

Answer (score 1):

You have `trigger` on your table, that does something and that `trigger` produces that row count message. I can reproduce this behavior with `instead of update trigger`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
go

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL)
go

insert into Table_1 values(1),(2),(3),(4)
update Table_1 set ID = 2 where ID = 1
```

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_Table_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Table_1'. 
> The statement has been terminated.

```
create trigger [tr_Table_1] on [Table_1]
instead of update 
as 
begin
    insert into [dbo].[Table_2]
    select * from [dbo].[Table_1]
    update Table_1 set ID = 2 where ID = 1
end
go

update Table_1 set ID = 2 where ID = 1
```

> (4 row(s) affected) 
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure
>   tr_Table_1, Line 8 
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Table_1'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table_1'. 
> The statement has
>   been terminated.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, Giorgi.